# Can someone please check my answers for these questions regarding improper integrals?

Tags: improper-integrals

a) Evaluate $$\int^{1}_{0.5} \frac{1}{x^2}dx$$

my answer: $-1+\frac{1}{0.5}=1$

b) Explain why  $$\int^{-1}_{1} \frac{1}{x^2}dx$$ is undefined.

my answer: since the function $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is undefined at $x=0$, the integral is undefined.

c) Evaluate $$\int^{k}_{1} \frac{1}{x^2}dx$$ for some positive number $k$

my answer: $\int^{k}_{1} \frac{1}{x^2}dx = \frac{-1}{x} |^{k}_{1} = \frac{-1}{k}+1$

d) Take the limit of your answer in part c as $k\rightarrow \infty $ What value would you assign $\int^{\infty}_{1} \frac{1}{x^2}dx$?

my answer: $\lim_{k\to\infty} [\frac{-1}{k}+1]=1$

$\frac{-1}{x} |^{\infty}_{1}=1$

Answer (score 1):

For any expression $h(x)$, 
let $\lim_{x \to k^+} h(x)$ denote the limit of $h(x)$ as $x$ approaches $k$, **from above**.

Similarly,
let $\lim_{x \to k^-} h(x)$ denote the limit of $h(x)$ as $x$ approaches $k$, **from below**.

> b) Explain why  $$\int^{-1}_{1} \frac{1}{x^2}dx$$ is undefined.

Let $f(x)$ denote $\frac{1}{x^2}$, which implies that $f(x)$ is well defined throughout $(-1,1)$, except at $x=0$.

Therefore, from the definition of improper integrals,

$$I = \int_1^{-1} f(x)dx = I_1 + I_2$$

where

$$I_1 = \lim_{b \to 0^+} \int_1^b f(x)dx$$

and

$$I_2 = \lim_{a \to 0^-} \int_a^{(-1)} f(x)dx.$$

This means that in order for $I$ to *exist* (i.e. be well defined) it is necessary (and sufficient) that **each of** $I_1$ and $I_2$ be (separately) well defined.  Failure with respect to *either* $I_1$ or $I_2$ is sufficient to conclude that $I$ is not well defined.

Therefore, the problem reduces to showing that $I_1$ is not well defined (i.e. that the corresponding limit does **not** exist).

$$\int_1^b f(x)dx = F(b) - F(1)$$

where

$$F(x) = \frac{-1}{x}.$$

Therefore,

$$\int_1^b f(x)dx = \frac{-1}{b} - \frac{-1}{1} = \frac{b-1}{b}.$$

Therefore,

$$I_1 = \lim_{b \to 0^+} \frac{b-1}{b}.$$

As you can see, as $b \to 0^+,$ the above numerator goes to $-1$, and the above denominator goes to $0$, from above.  Therefore, as $b \to 0^+, I_1 \to -\infty.$

Therefore, $I_1$ is not well defined.

Therefore, $I$ is not well defined.

Answer (score 0):

a) Fine.

b) I would add that the function isn't *bounded*.

c) You switched the order of the integration limits by mistake.

d) error follows from previous part.

Comment: I just fixed it, can you check now?

Comment: @user130306 Looks good to me. Well done.